# HTTP error: Bad request in socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, http, client-server, httpclient

I wrote a basic C program that establishes a connection with the IP address of `google.com` and then starts receiving data from client.

But firstly, during compilation the following warning is generated:

```
test.c:12:25: warning: implicit declaration
      of function 'inet_addr' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
address.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("2...
                        ^
1 warning generated.
```

Secondly, on running the program, the following output is generated:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
ContGET/HTTP/1.1
```

What changes can I make in my code to successfully receive data from an HTTP server ?

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_port = htons(80);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("216.58.200.196");
    connect(mySocket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
    char msg[21] = "GET/HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    send(mySocket, msg, 21, 0);
    char msgRecv[100];
    recv(mySocket, msgRecv, 100, 0);
    printf("%s", msgRecv);
}
```

Comment: This HTTP request is wrong in multiple ways (at least missing spaces, no host header). Please study the standard if you really want to implement  HTTP yourself, that what standards are for.

Comment: About the implicit declaration warning - you are missing the right `#include`, see https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the appropriate http request would be in this case ? I'm a beginner in socket programming

Comment: @DebalGhosh like Steffen told you, you need to read the HTTP 1.1 standard spec, it outlines everything you need to know. Start with [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), and its successors RFCs 7230-7235.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many faults (lack of error handling, misusing `send()`, `recv()` and `printf()`, etc), but the main cause of the HTTP  failure is because your HTTP request is malformed.

If you read the HTTP 1.1 protocol specification, [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and its successors RFCs 7230-7235, you will see that you are missing required space characters between `GET` and `/`, and between `/` and `HTTP`, and that you are also missing a required `Host` header.

At a bare minimum, your HTTP request needs to look like this instead:

```c
char msg[] = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Once you have that working, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16247097/65863) for the kind of logic you will need to implement afterwards to receive the server's response *properly* (a single call to `recv()` won't cut it, not even close).